# Do male guinea pigs do their mating dance before mounting other male guinea pigs?

Tags: behavior, rabbits, guinea-pigs

#### Do male guinea pigs perform their mating dance before attempting to mounting other male guinea pigs?

I recently adopted a guinea pig and find it strange that he's dancing for both my female rabbit as well as my male rabbit.  Is this just typical guinea pig behavior?  or might it just be because my rabbit is fixed? or just because he's a different species?

Comment: Cavies are very social... and not terribly bright about effective sexual techniques.  Which is more interesting since Female cavies seem to sense when the time is right and will usually refuse bad matings and casual encounters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen male and female guinea pigs doing the "dominance dance" to both male and female guinea pigs. I called it "dominance dance" because that's essentially what the guinea pig is doing, establishing dominance for mounting a female, claim space, etc.
It's perfectly normal for cavies to do it, don't worry.